HTML table width not applied for only one row
I have a table with fixed layout, it has two rows.
In the first the width is working as they are 50%-45%-5%.
In the second row I tried to set it to 30%-20%-50% but it does not work.
I tried by removing table-layout: fixed and it works. But I'd need it to work with it on both rows.

expected result: 


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 1.1rem;" width="50%">
        <b>Customer Sales Order</b>
      </td>
      <td width="45%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="20%">Delivery date:</td>
              <td>22/03/2024</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Page</td>
              <td>1/1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Account:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>325535</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>VAT Number:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Fiscal Code:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>{bank}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Port:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Inv1:</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>{inv}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Inv2:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="20%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Categ.:</td>
              <td>{categ}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Place:</td>
              <td>{place}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" width="50%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">Payment:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">31</td>
              <td width="70%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">Bank:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{bank}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">Agent:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{bank}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10px">Curr.:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{curr}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">D/i type:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">1</td>
              <td width="70%">{type}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">S.ord.Inv.:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{s_ord_Inv};</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




You can't do that. All row-columns are the same width in each row. You can't change the width in a separate row.

@Paulie_D Why does it work on the first row but not on the second?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#fixed: "In the fixed table layout algorithm, the width of each column is determined as follows: - A column element with explicit width sets the width for that column. - Otherwise, a cell in the first row with explicit width determines the width for that column."

You could use colgroup to define the width of each individual column. This way each column gets assigned a fix width. Inside a specific row you can then use colspan to merge cells according to your needs:


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" width="100%">
<colgroup>
  <col width="30%">
  <col width="20%">
  <col width="45%">
  <col width="5%">
</colgroup>
  <tbody>
<tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 1.1rem;">
        <b>Customer Sales Order</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="20%">Delivery date:</td>
              <td>22/03/2024</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Page</td>
              <td>1/1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Account:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>325535</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>VAT Number:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Fiscal Code:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>{bank}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Port:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Inv1:</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>{inv}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Inv2:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Categ.:</td>
              <td>{categ}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Place:</td>
              <td>{place}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">Payment:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">31</td>
              <td width="70%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">Bank:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{bank}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">Agent:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{bank}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10px">Curr.:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{curr}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">D/i type:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">1</td>
              <td width="70%">{type}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">S.ord.Inv.:</td>
              <td style="text-align:center" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="70%">{s_ord_Inv};</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



